# Is it possible to use API Routes as Proxy to my existing RoR Backend

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Every time NextJs request for an api, it will come first to api routes before it redirected to my RoR backend service.

I use this to encrypt my access token to session NextJS using iron-session once I get the data from backend.

```js
## src/pages/api/login.ts
const loginRoute = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const response = await fetch(`backend-service/authorizations.json`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
    })
  })
    .then((res) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        return res.text().then((text) => {
          throw new Error(text)
        })
      }
      return res
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(401).json({ message: err })
    })

  if (response) {
    req.session.user = response
    await req.session.save()
    res.json(response)
  }
}
export default withSessionRoute(loginRoute)
```

Is this a valid use case for API Routes in NextJS?

Thanks in advance!